# which is better for CPU usage waiting for a function returned with std::future wait() or check a flag sleep for a while in a loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wait

Q1: which occupies less CPU usage, future wait() or check flag in a while loop?

```
std::atomic_bool isRunning{false};

void foo(){
    isRunning.store(true);
    doSomethingTimeConsuming();
    isRunning.store(false);
}

std::future f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
```

use std::future wait():

```
if(f.vaild())
   f.wait()
```

check flag in a while loop:

```
if(f.valid){
    while(isRunning.load())
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
}
```

Q2: is the conclusion also applied to std::thread.join() or std::condition_variable.wait() ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Any wait operation would require less CPU than sleeping shortly in a loop. During wait, the thread release CPU time slice, so it is available for other threads that needs it, whereas a loop requires the thread to get time slice (after the exiting sleep)

Comment: The `wait` is likely blocking on a synchronization primitive such as a conditional variable. Highly efficient.  Way more efficient than polling in a tight loop.

Comment: Also on average the final sleep will be twice as long as necessary. The wait won't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::this_thread::sleep_for` keeps waking up the thread unnecessarily at wrong times. The average latency of the result being ready and the waiter thread noticing it is half the `sleep_for` timeout.

`std::future::wait` is more efficient because it blocks in the kernel till the result is ready, without doing multiple syscalls unnecessarily, unlike `std::this_thread::sleep_for`.

If your run the two versions with

```
void doSomethingTimeConsuming() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

under `perf stat`, the results for `std::future::wait` are:

```
          1.803578      task-clock (msec)         #    0.002 CPUs utilized          
                 2      context-switches          #    0.001 M/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               116      page-faults               #    0.064 M/sec                  
         6,356,215      cycles                    #    3.524 GHz                    
         4,511,076      instructions              #    0.71  insn per cycle         
           835,604      branches                  #  463.304 M/sec                  
            22,313      branch-misses             #    2.67% of all branches
```

Whereas for `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms)`:

```
         11.715249      task-clock (msec)         #    0.012 CPUs utilized          
               901      context-switches          #    0.077 M/sec                  
                 6      cpu-migrations            #    0.512 K/sec                  
               118      page-faults               #    0.010 M/sec                  
        40,177,222      cycles                    #    3.429 GHz                      
        25,401,055      instructions              #    0.63  insn per cycle
         2,286,806      branches                  #  195.199 M/sec  
           156,400      branch-misses             #    6.84% of all branches
```

I.e. in this particular test, `sleep_for` burns roughly 6 times as many CPU cycles.

---

Note that there is a race condition between `isRunning.load()` and `isRunning.store(true)`. A fix is to initialize `isRunning{true};`.